# Python : How to remove focus from button when click anywhere on window

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy-language

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy` .When i run `test.py` then i set `focus` on `button`.After that i click anywhere on window using mouse then focus does not remove . Because after click on window i press enter then it call  `def self.add()`.
Can someone tell me how to remove `focus` from button when click anywhere on
window ?

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (500, 150)


class User(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.name_focus, 1)

    def name_focus(self, *args):
        self.postUser.focus = True
        self.postUser.background_color = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1]


    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if (hasattr(self.postUser, 'focus') and self.postUser.focus) and keycode == 40:
            self.add()

    def add(self):
        print('button Event Call')


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

User:
    name: name
    postUser : postUser
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 20, 20
            spacing: 10, 10

            Label:
                text: "Name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
            TextInput:
                id:name
                text_size: self.size
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 0, 0
            spacing: 5, 0
            size_hint: .5, .35
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': 0}

            Button:
                id:postUser
                size_hint_x: .5
                text: "Ok"
                focus: False
                on_release:
                    root.add()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `on_touch_up` method in your `User` class.

```
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if (hasattr(self.postUser, 'focus') and self.postUser.focus):
        self.postUser.focus = False
        self.postUser.background_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I am posting complete code.

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (500, 150)


class User(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.name_focus, 1)

    def name_focus(self, *args):
        self.postUser.focus = True
        self.postUser.background_color = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1]


    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if (hasattr(self.postUser, 'focus') and self.postUser.focus) and keycode == 40:
            self.add()

    def add(self):
        print('button Event Call')

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if (hasattr(self.postUser, 'focus') and self.postUser.focus):
            self.postUser.focus = False
            self.postUser.background_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

User:
    name: name
    postUser : postUser
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 20, 20
            spacing: 10, 10

            Label:
                text: "Name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
            TextInput:
                id:name
                text_size: self.size
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 0, 0
            spacing: 5, 0
            size_hint: .5, .35
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': 0}

            Button:
                id:postUser
                size_hint_x: .5
                text: "Ok"
                focus: False
                on_release:
                    root.add()
```